# How do I resolve this paradox of counting line segments?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

If I have some uncountable proper subset $T$ of transcendental numbers on the real line, by definition I can't count them.  Now suppose I take the complement of this set.  I now have a set of line segments defined in-between each pair of points, one fewer segments than there were transcendental numbers the original set.  But every line segment contains a rational number and therefore the number of segments is countable.

This appears to contradict the independence of the continuum hypothesis from some reasonable maths theory in which the above description is expressed.

Where am I going wrong?

---

Update: Is the problem that I am defining line segments between distinct rational numbers with potentially no lower limit on length?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56393/discussion-on-question-by-robert-frost-how-do-i-resolve-this-paradox-of-counting).

Comment: Having trouble making any sense of this question at all.  I guess when you say the complement of T is "a set of line segments in-between each pair of points", you mean it's "the union of a disjoint set of open intervals, each interval being from one element of T to the next higher element of T".   It would be helpful to clarify that, for starters.  Once we do that, it's clear that the construction simply makes no sense: a given element of T doesn't necessarily have a next higher element of T, so no, the complement of T isn't necessarily a disjoint set of open intervals.

Comment: @DonHatch the key point is that there's only a next highest t if t is discrete so we can conclude there's no such thing as uncountable many discrete points. Which I did not appreciate until Noah pointed it out.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your argument *does prove something*. Namely, it proves:

> There is no uncountable set of reals which is *right-discrete* - every element in the set has a next element in the set.

*(Note that you talk about transcendentals specifically, but there is nothing special about them - we can just talk about reals. And the same statement is true for left-discrete sets, of course.)*

The proof is exactly the argument they give. Suppose $X$ were a discrete uncountable set of reals. Then to each $x\in X$ we can assign an interval $I_x$ to $x$: let $I_x=(x, y)$ where $y$ is the next element of $X$.

Now this construction begs the question: $$\mbox{How do we know there is such a $y$ in the first place?}$$ Well, we know that because *$X$ is discrete* (by assumption). So we're good to go. But note that this step is **not true for general $X$**.

OK, now we argue as follows. Let $q_x$ be some rational in $I_x$; there are lots of rationals in $I_x$ since $x<y$, so this is doable *(and the rationals are well-orderable (not well-ordered - careful!), so we may always "pick one" even without the axiom of choice)*. But it's easy to show that $I_u\cap I_v=\emptyset$ if $u, v$ are distinct elements of $X$, so the map $x\mapsto q_x$ is an injection from $X$ into $\mathbb{Q}$; and this contradicts the assumption that $X$ was uncountable. $\quad \Box$

*(Aw heck, I committed the "logician's sin" - I wrote a proof by contradiction where none is needed! We can just argue directly that if $X$ is right-discrete, then $X$ is countable, by building the injection into $\mathbb{Q}$. I wrote this as a proof by contradiction instead, to better parallel the OP's argument.)*

---

But this is not what you claimed! The result you *want* is (somehow) that there is no uncountable set of transcendentals; and neither that nor any related statement is true. The only way your argument works at all is if the set in question is assumed to be discrete, or "pretty discrete" anyways.

Comment: This is a masterpiece.

Comment: Thanks. The fact that $T$ must somewhere be not discrete largely nails it. I am however struggling with one last notion - how a set of only transcendentals can be somewhere "not discrete". Is this possible? I guess we just say take some segment and remove the algebraic numbers?

Comment: and we have exactly that - a set of transcendental numbers which is not discrete.

Comment: @RobertFrost Well, the set of *all* transcendentals is not discrete - neither is the set of transcendentals between $2$ and $17$, or the set of transcendentals whose third decimal digit is $8$, or ...

Comment: Good we're all in accordance then. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 8):

Let's suppose for a moment that we know that between any two transcendentals there's another transcendental. The let your set $S$ contain *all* transcendentals, and let's follow your argument.

> Now suppose I take the complement of this set. I now have a set of
>   line segments defined in-between each pair of points, one fewer
>   segments than there were transcendental numbers the original set

So we take all non-transcendental numbers, and you say that this consists of a set of line segments, one between each pair of points. (I assume you mean here "between each adjacent pair of points", i.e., that your segments do not overlap). Suppose $(p, q)$ is such a segment, i.e., that $p$ and $q$ are adjacent transcendentals. Then there's a transcendental between $p$ and $q$, by our assumption at the top of this answer. So they're not actually "adjacent". In short, with the assumption at the top (and the assumption of nonoverlapping intervals), your construction fails.

On the other hand, if the intervals are allowed to overlap, then for each transcendental $p$, you just take the interval $(p, p+1)$. There's certainly one rational in this interval, and indeed, infinitely many. And all rationals get counted infinitely many times, so you cannot say that the number of intervals is countable.

Comment: I accept the construction fails for "all transcendentals" but I think there's a more general reason for failure which I've now added to the question. I suspect a set of uncountably many transcendental numbers is not possible without having some algebraic numbers in there.

Comment: I think that the secret here is that nowhere in your construction did you use any property of the transcendentals. Therefore, if correct, your argument would apply equally well to, say, the irrationals.

Comment: I used the property that there can be uncountably many of them.

Comment: "I suspect a set of uncountably many transcendental numbers is not possible without having some algebraic numbers in there." **No** - the set of all transcendentals is a set of uncountably many transcendentals not containing any algebraic number!

Comment: Yes, Robert, but that property also applies to the irrationals. I should have said "your argument would apply equally well to any uncountable set."

Answer (score 4):

Once more, let's follow your construction. It's supposed to work for any set of uncountably many transcendental numbers, so I'm going to take as my set $S$ the set of *all* transcendentals.

---

Useful lemma: because $\pi$ is transcendental, $q_n = (1 + \frac{1}{n})\pi$ is also transcendental.

Proof: suppose that for some polynomial $p$, $p(q_n) = 0$. Let 
$$
s(x) = p(\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right) x).
$$
Then $s(\pi) = 0$, and that's a contradiction. QED.

---

(1) I take the complement of this set, and you say that I have the set of (open) line segments defined in between points.

(2) Because $\pi \in S$, you claim there must be a line segment starting at $\pi$ and going to the next transcendental, which I'll call $t$.

(3) Because $t$ is the next transcendental, there are no transcendentals between $\pi$ and $t$. [Stop me when I say something that's not what you intended!]

(4) Let's look at the number $t - \pi$.

(5) Because $q_1 = 2\pi$ is transcendental, by the lemma, we must have $t < q_1$, so $t - \pi < \pi$.

(6) Because $q_2 = \frac{3}{2} \pi$ is transcendental, by the lemma, we must have $t < q_2$, so $t - \pi < \frac{\pi}{2}$.

(7) By the same argument, for any integer $n$, we have that $t - \pi < \frac{\pi}{n}$.

(8) Hence $t \le \pi$. But since $t$ is the "next" transcendental, we know that $t > \pi$.

That's a contradiction.

Your assumption that there's a "next" irrational, made in step 2, must be false.

Answer (score 2):

While almost every idea necessary to understand this "paradox" is in an answer or comment somewhere, I haven't yet seen anyone concisely point out the actual error in the OP. So here goes:

*"Now suppose I take the complement of this set. I now have a set of line segments defined in-between each pair of points, one fewer segments than there were transcendental numbers the original set."*

This assertion is false.

The intuition is presumably that if we have a set of $100$ real numbers, and take the complement of that set in the real numbers, then the result is in fact $99$ open line segments (together with two infinite rays that are irrelevant).

But for infinite sets, it's quite unlikely that the complement of the set in the real numbers consists of open line segments. There's just no reason that it should, despite our intuition about finite sets. (And indeed, if we examine the proof for complements of finite sets, we see that it depends upon each element of our set having a "next element to its right", and now we've merged back to other answers.)

Comment: The intuition is, that the original set contained only transcendental numbers, and there is no pair of transcendental numbers which does not define a line segment. The problem comes in defining closest pairs, which we cannot do since there is no 'next' element anywhere our set is dense. But I now need to think some more whether this is only a constructibility issue as it does look very like Schroeder Bernstein and we can't have our cake and eat it.

Comment: I claim this really has nothing to do with transcendality. Indeed, I think your comment restates mine: pairs (and finite subsets of $\Bbb R$) act differently from infinite subsets of $\Bbb R$.

Comment: to make sure I understand correctly, you mean uncountably infinite subsets of $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: In fact, this difference happens even for countably infinite subsets of $\Bbb R$. What if your set *is* the rationals themselves? Does the complement of the rationals in the reals look like the union of line segments?

Comment: I think we're confusing subsets which contain infinitely many elements with subsets of which there are infinitely many

Answer (score 1):

I'm having hard times understanding how the segments would be generated, after removing one trascendental number there is just no "next" trascendental one to connect: between any two there will always be one (infinite) others. I'm supposing that no "segment" can exist between couple of trascendental numbers.

Comment: Every distinct pair has a segment in-between. How can two distinct real numbers not define a line segment?

Comment: What does "distinct" mean in your comment?

Comment: Two numbers certainly define a segment, but if you are going to take away from this segment the trascendental numbers it includes (there are infinitely many) it is no longer going to be an uninterrupted segment! You cannot ever have two "adjacent" trascendental numbers to join to define a segment that is not going to be divided by other trascendental numbers in between.

Comment: @lesath82 only the two transcendental numbers, one at either end, are removed, not all those in-between.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this sentence:

```
But every line segment contains a rational number and therefore the number of segments is countable.
```

The 'therefore' is invalid.  You are inferring a 1-1 mapping between line segments and rationals in order to infer line-segment countability from rationals-countability.  The problem is that the mapping you have inferred is nowhere near 1-1 - any line segment can contain infinitely-many rationals, and any given rational can be contained in infinitely-many line segments.  These infinities *need not be equal* - while any line segment can of course contain only countably many rationals, it is quite possible for a rational to be contained in UNcountably many line segments.

What you would need to establish is this property: Every line segment contains a rational *which is contained by no other line segment*.  THAT would yield a 1-1 mapping.  Unfortunately, THAT property cannot be established for -any- uncountable set of points.

Comment: Every segment as defined does contain a rational not in any other segment as the segments are disjoint. The problem is, no uncountable proper subset of the transcendental numbers is everywhere discrete and therefore there isn't always a "next" transcendental with which to construct the disjoint line segments. In the limit, the segments converge to length $0$ from one transcendental number to itself - a contradiction with the notion of containing an algebraic number.

Comment: @Robert Frost: The submitter *didn't explicitly say* the segments were intended to be disjoint.  He said - and I quote - '... line segments defined in between each pair of points...'.  Last time I checked, if you had (say) three successive points, that defines three line segments - with the longest overlapping each of the other two.  [Of course, it is plain from the assertion '... one fewer segments than there were ...' that the submitter *intends* only the segments between adjacent points - but as others noted, that assumes there ARE adjacent points.]

Comment: Actually, I forgot that the submitter is taking the *complement* of the transcendental set, and *assumes* that it consists solely of line segments.  In fact, it could contain an uncountable number of points which occur in NO line segment.  [in fact, the set doesn't have to consist of transcendentals, or even be uncountable - consider the complement of the rationals.  Something like that could easily occur]

Comment: It can't be the complement of the rationals because it is the complement of a set of only transcendental numbers.